# Gnuplot, how a make multiplot share one x-axis?

Tags: gnuplot

Using gnuplot, I am able to make multiplot successfully with my four columns data, the first column is time, x-data, the others are three y-data. So now the problem is that even I did not set the xlabel for the first two subplots or even if I `set tmargin 0` or even I `unset xtics`, there is still large white space between the subplots. I hope to get an effect that the subplots are only separated by ONE x-axis. Any solution?

Comment: Do you mean something like [multiplot - stacking 3 graphs on a larger canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133002/2604213)? Would be easier if you would post your current script content.