# Gnuplot multiplot with one colorbox

Tags: plot, size, gnuplot, colorbox

I have a layout of 3,1 plots using multiplot. All of the three plots have the same scales, so I just want to show one colorbox, on the right margin. However, once I unset the colorbox for the first two plot, the size of the three plot are different.
Can anybody tell me how to implement this with the three plots have the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set a fixed right margin with e.g. `set rmargin at screen 0.85`. That sets the right border of the plot at 85% of the image size:

```
set multiplot layout 3,1

set rmargin at screen 0.85
plot x 
plot x
plot x linecolor palette
unset multiplot
set output
```

Output with 4.6.3:

[image]

See also the related question [multiplot - stacking 3 graphs on a larger canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19131509/2604213).

### Generic solution for fixed margins

If you want a layout with one row and three columns, can use the `multiplot` options `margins` and `spacing` to get three plots which have the same width:

```
set xlabel 'xlabel'
set ylabel 'ylabel'

set multiplot layout 1,3 margins 0.1,0.9,0.1,0.95 spacing 0.05

plot x

unset ylabel
plot x

plot x linecolor palette

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: BUt what if the layout is 1,3? I mean the three figures are in the same row.

Comment: @meatball See the edited answer for a rather generic way to layout n columns.