# Gnuplot overlapping ytics in multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot several graphs stacked vertically with no space between them using multiplot in gnuplot. My problem is that ytics of the different plots overlap. I know this can be avoided by defining a range for ytics, but I have to make 37 different multiplots with 4 stacked plots in each one so manually setting ranges is not an option.

So I was wondering if there was some way to force ytics not to overlap from within gnuplot of if the only option is to calculate and manually specify ytics range.

[This is what I want to avoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGDtu.png)

I thought of using `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX` an `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN` variables and use them changed by a factor of 20% to define the ytics range. This approach works, but I don't know how to round them so that they can adapt to different kinds of data, meaning that if they range from 0.3145 to 9.7601 they are rounded to 0 and 10 with 5 divisions but if the range goes from 0.3145 to 0.3150 they are rounded to  0.3145 to 0.3150 with 5 divisions)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133002/2604213

Comment: @Christoph as I mention I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve manually setting the ytics range

Comment: The main point was the use of `set offsets` which does that